# To sustain the value of a variable

Tags: java, swing

My code is as follows:

```
private void okJButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    srcLang=(srcLangJComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString());
    targLang=(targLangJComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString());
           infoNew.this.setVisible(false);
}                                         

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static String[] newButton() {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(infoNew.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(infoNew.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(infoNew.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(infoNew.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new infoNew().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    System.out.println(srcLang);
    return new String[]{srcLang,targLang};
}
```

There are two functions lower one invoking the upper function as a jframe button the upper function receives the value of two variables which are of public in nature but the values assigned them to here is not available in the lower function.

The value assigned to the variables srcLang and tarLang in the function okJButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)

is not available in the

function newButton().

P.S. variables srcLang and targLang are declared as public static

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Very very very confusing. Please add more "meat" to your question.

Comment: I still do not see where the "lower one invokes the upper one." Where in the static function is the instance method, okJButtonActionPerformed, being invoked?

Comment: Please see my updated answer with another work-around if the method must remain static.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use static methods.

Instead you need to create a class that contains your code so you can define `instance` variables. Then once you create an instance variable you can access the variable from any method in your class.

Maybe start with the `ButtonDemo` example code from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html). It shows how to create a panel with instance variables for the buttons. Then the buttons can be accessed in other methods of the class.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this post (although there is not a formal question) is that the method `newButton()` is static, and the variables `srcLang` and `tarLang` are instance variables.

**Updated Answer: (Not Best Practice)**

A `static` method can be called from either an `instance` or a `static` method. An `instance` method requires an `instance` of the class to be called. What you can do is pass a copy of the instance that you are using (you can use the `this` keyword if you are working within an instance method) and call the instance method from the static method, however, I would suggest that you attempt to make the method `static` as I describe here:

You have another option that I thought of: you can convert the instance variables in the `okJButtonActionPerformed` function to `static` and this should be fine.

```
private static void okJButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
```

**Older Part of Answer: (Best Practice)**

Static methods do not require an instance of the class to run, whereas instance variables do require a formal declaration of the object.

To fix this, you could try and remove the `static` in front of the `newButton()` method:

Change: `public static String[] newButton() {`

to: `public String[] newButton() {`

At this point, without seeing more of your code (because there is no main method, and I do not know where these methods are being called from), this is about as much information as I can provide. If you would like a more detailed answer, please post more sample code.

Comment: I am calling this function from another static function so I cannot remove static.

Comment: Can you show the static function that you are calling it from?

Comment: `I am calling this function from another static function so I cannot remove static.` - that is your problem you should NOT be using static methods everywhere in your code. Read the tutorial for a better structured program. The tutorial has a working example. Learn by using working code instead of writing your own code!

Comment: I am calling it from here                                        private void newJButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)   i removed the the static keyword as suggested by you then in this method I am getting the error :non-static method newButton() cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: Were you able to see my updated answer about making the vars static that you were not able to access? If you don't want to make it static, you can pass in the instance of the object you are working with into the static method and call the vars. Does this make sense?

Comment: I have updated my answer with more info. Does this help?